# how to have a button refresh the page on send and also have iframe scroll to the bottom of the frame using the same button simultaneously on reload

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, iframe, scroll

Hellow there, id like to make my iframe scroll to the very bottom where the new output shows on every reload which is being triggered by a button, I've researched the question and it seems to be rather hard to find an answer, scrolling an iframe automatically to the bottom or triggering its scrolling to both seems to be a rather complicated or tricky matter and has been bugging me for a month, I know a good bit about HTML and CSS but still have some issues with java if jquery should need to be used, I know enough to understand how it works but need plenty reference if anyone can help, id appreciate it 1000 times over, thank you! (basically i need to have an iframe stay constantly scrolled to the bottom-) here's my code so far for the HTML parts-

````
<h3>"words and stuff"</h3>
<p>
<div class="demo">
<iframe src="page1.php" width="400" height="400" scrolling="yes" font-family: "Courier New", "Lucida Console", monospace; name="myIframe"; id="myIframe"; class="demo">
</iframe>
</div>  

<form method="post" action="page2.php">
<input type="textarea" class="input-txt" placeholder="more words and stuff" name = "input">

<div2>
<input type="submit" value="even more words and stuff" onClick="window.location.href=window.location.href">
</p>
</div2>
</form>```
````

Comment: You want a button to reload an iframe and scroll to the bottom?

Comment: i already have a button that reloads on send, but I want that same button, when clicked to send and reload, to also scroll *only the iframe, not the whole page* to the bottom so i can see the new output at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

To scroll to the bottom of an `<iframe>`, use:

```js
iframe.contentWindow.scrollTo(0, iframe.contentDocument.documentElement.scrollHeight);
```

Take note that this will not work if the `<iframe>` has a different origin than the origin of your website

Full example:

```html
<iframe src="https://stacksnippets.net"></iframe>
<br/>
<button>Reload & Scroll To Bottom</button>
<script>
const iframe = document.querySelector('iframe');
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function(){
  iframe.contentWindow.location = iframe.src;
  iframe.contentWindow.scrollTo(0, iframe.contentDocument.documentElement.scrollHeight);
})
</script>
```

Comment: omg thank you!! also- where in the code exactly do I put this? do I use it like?: ```<iframe iframe.contentWindow.scrollTo(0, iframe.contentWindow.height);></iframe>```

Comment: also, the iframe is receiving information inserted into a textbox that is sent to a PHPMyAdmin server connected to the website, so this should still work, right?

Comment: @KitchenUtensils Yes it should. I've updated my answer so you know how to include it.

Comment: it still doesnt seem to be working for me- here's all the scripting for the page currently, see if I incorporated it correctly- ```<script src="javascript/main.js"></script>
  <script language="JavaScript">
onload = function()
{
 document.myIframe.document.body.style.fontFamily = "Courier New", "Lucida Console", monospace;
}
</script>
<script>
document.querySelector('iframe').contentWindow.scrollTo(0, iframe.contentWindow.height);
</script>```

Comment: i feel im getting as annoying as this problem is to me most likely- but its- *coughs* still not working- lemme show you how i used that  ```<script src="javascript/main.js"></script>
  <script language="JavaScript">
onload = function()
{
 document.myIframe.document.body.style.fontFamily = "Courier New", "Lucida Console", monospace;
}

const iframe = document.querySelector('iframe');
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function(){
  iframe.contentWindow.location = iframe.src;
  iframe.contentWindow.scrollTo(0, iframe.contentWindow.height);
})


</script>```

Comment: @KitchenUtensils Is that your full HTML? Where have you defined the `<iframe>`?

Comment: im sorry, heres the iframe html-  ```<div class="demo"><iframe src="page1.php" width="400" height="400" scrolling="yes" font-family: "Courier New", "Lucida Console", monospace; name="myIframe"; id="myIframe"; class="demo"></iframe></div>```

Comment: @KitchenUtensils You're on the right track. Add `<button>Reload & Scroll To Bottom</button>` *after* the iframe and try clicking it.

Comment: heres the iframe, textbox, and button html/css code i *already* have for the button- is there a bug in it that's not letting it work? :

Comment: ```<div class="demo"><iframe src="page1.php" width="400" height="400" scrolling="yes" font-family: "Courier New", "Lucida Console", monospace; name="myIframe"; id="myIframe"; class="demo"></iframe></div>  

<form method="post" action="page2.php"><input type="textarea" class="input-txt" placeholder="stuff" name = "input" style="height:20px;width:392px; background-color:pink; border-color:gray; border-style:dotted dashed solid double; color:gray">```

Comment: ```<div2><input type="submit" value="stuff" style="height:20px;width:400px; background-color:pink; border-color:gray; border-style:dotted dashed solid double; color:gray" onClick="window.location.href=window.location.href"></p></div2>```

Comment: (i guess i should start tagging you O.O-)

Comment: i ran just purely the code you gave also- unincluded in my project, (either than the reload part) and by itself it showed up correctly but still didn't scroll the page down- I'm getting legitimately stumped on whats wrong-

Comment: @KitchenUtensils Sorry about that. I'll take a look.

Comment: actual;y im really very sorry, its been an issue for over a month- I'm just thankful you tried to help<3 ill keep working on some of those suggestions you gave and see if I can make it work or if I'm missing something-

Comment: @KitchenUtensils Try the code again - I've fixed the scrolling issue.

Comment: i finnaly got it to scroll to bottom when I click the button, but I've had to put and extra button for that since it is a "button" and the submit/refresh button is an "input type= submit" so- is there any way to make this line of code work for the "input" rather than "button" if that makes sense-? also- (the iframe will be missing from this code sample since its incorporated above but it DOES reference a valid i frame-)

Comment: ```<button>Reload & Scroll To Bottom</button>
<script>
const iframe = document.querySelector('iframe');
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function(){
  iframe.contentWindow.scrollTo(0, iframe.contentDocument.documentElement.scrollHeight);
})
</script>```

Comment: actually nevermind that- heres the latest issue, I have this code:  ```<div2><button><input type="submit" value="stuff" style="height:50px;width:400px; background-color:pink; border-color:gray; border-style:dotted dashed solid double; color:gray" onClick="window.location.href=window.location.href"></button></p></div2>

<script>
const iframe = document.querySelector('iframe');
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function(){
  iframe.contentWindow.scrollTo(0, iframe.contentDocument.documentElement.scrollHeight);
})
</script>``` (continue. next comment)

Comment: i have that code, and it kicks the scrollbar to the bottom but the refresh comes after and kicks it back to the top instantly- so how do i put the scrolling down after the refresh-?

Comment: @KitchenUtensils Can you put your full code somewhere on for example, jsfiddle? It would be much easier to replicate and fix the issue. Thanks

Comment: i can try, and btw, is there any way to pm you?

Comment: btw, i tried and im not sure how to save something to jsfiddle so it can be shared with you-

Comment: any developments on this-? O^O