# Id like to use a button to scroll an iframe to the bottom, but the code given in an answer doesnt seem to work for that

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, scroll, reload

i recently made a post about getting a button to scroll and iframe scrollbar automatically to the bottom when pressed, I was given an answer yet when I run the code given in the answer it still doesn't work, does anyone know why this is?

(here's the link to the original post: [how to have a button refresh the page on send and also have iframe scroll to the bottom of the frame using the same button simultaneously on reload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67989331/how-to-have-a-button-refresh-the-page-on-send-and-also-have-iframe-scroll-to-the/67989609?noredirect=1#comment120174163_67989609))

and the code given in the answer:

````
<p>
<div class="demo">
<iframe src="page1.php" width="400" height="400" scrolling="yes" font-family: "Courier New", "Lucida Console", monospace; name="myIframe"; id="myIframe"; class="demo">
</iframe>
</div>  

<form method="post" action="page2.php">
<input type="textarea" class="input-txt" placeholder="more words and stuff" name = "input">

<div2>
<input type="submit" value="even more words and stuff" onClick="window.location.href=window.location.href">
</p>
</div2>
</form>```
````

Comment: And somehow you thought by asking exact same question again will get you a correct answer? It doesn't work here like that. prepare this question get flooded with down votes and get closed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to have a button refresh the page on send and also have iframe scroll to the bottom of the frame using the same button simultaneously on reload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67989331/how-to-have-a-button-refresh-the-page-on-send-and-also-have-iframe-scroll-to-the)